# Filter settings in Oracle Views

Tags: oracle, ddl, sql-view

I have 2 views like this (simplified):

```
CREATE VIEW BASE_VIEW AS
(
      -- Simplified version, view actually does a lot more.
      SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
);

CREATE VIEW OUTER_VIEW AS
(
      -- The where clause here makes this view return half the rows as the above BASE_VIEW
      SELECT * FROM BASE_VIEW where SomeField = 'something'
);
```

My question is, shouldn't OUTER_VIEW execute in roughly half the time as the BASE_VIEW? I don't see this behavior. It almost takes the full time as it takes to execute BASE_VIEW.

Since Oracle compiles the referenced views into your outer view, I thought it would be intelligent enough to optimize the query based on the outer view's where clase. Should it not?

EDIT: In fact the "base view" query with the where clause from the "outer view" is taking half the time.

Comment: How many rows are you working with? Do you have access to the query plan? Is it an indexed table and is that column indexed?

Comment: note windowed functions will result in the first view being ran before the filter critter being applied but you do not appear to be using any just a heads up

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have an entire room full of different kinds of fruit scattered all over the place. The view BASE_VIEW is like saying, "Retrieve all fruit in this room."

The OUTER_VIEW is like saying, "Retrieve all oranges from this room." If the fruit is not ordered in some way, you will spend roughly the same amount of time as the BASE_VIEW to search for all the oranges.

Now imagine you have all the fruit separated in baskets. Grabbing all the oranges becomes easy because you know exactly where they are.

Adding an index on SomeField is what orders the data so that it doesn't have to search through the entire room of fruit. There are some restrictions on when an index could help or not. Based on the amount of rows in your table, the oracle optimizer might decide that it is faster to just grab all the rows anyway. I suggest you read through this guide to determine the proper way to index tables: [Use The Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/). It helped me a ton when starting out indexing.

If SomeField does not directly come from MYTABLE and is just a created field in BASE_VIEW, then it might help to index the field that creates SomeField. It is hard for us to know without seeing the data.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your comments, but query and table optimization is all taken care of already. In fact, running the "base" query with the where clause is taking half the time!